# Upper bounds on mixing times in MCMC for bayesian analysis in practice

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, bounds

I'm familiar with how, for a general markov chain with some transition kernel, the spectral gap and the log-Sobolev constant both provide an upper bound on mixing time. I also have heard people alluding to how these quantities might be used in general cases of MCMC to indicate convergence rates (for example, in [this set of lecture notes](http://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~pitman/s205s03/lecture28.pdf)).

In all of the material I've seen so far, in order to calculate these quantities, the transition kernel was needed. For many uses of MCMC, however, I don't  believe you have the kernel in hand (eg using MCMC to calculate a posterior in a Bayesian analysis).

So, my ultimate question is, can you place an upper bound on mixing time using the quantities above without having the kernel provided? Say with only a tentative generative model and the data at hand? Is there work out there on this? I haven't been able to find anything yet.

Comment: In MCMC for posterior analysis, the transition kernel is (generally) known. For example, for the Gibbs sampler, the transition kernel is the product of the full conditionals. In Metropolis-Hastings, the transition kernel is a function of the ratio of the posteriors evaluated at two points and thus the normalizing constant goes away.